# Powershell using get-acl to return only user/groupnames?

Tags: powershell, acl

I need to show all the domain\username|groupname of everyone who is allowed access to a particular folder to feed into another command (I'll be removing access for all users and setting new user rights), is there anyway to format a list that returns just this parameter? I know it's probably some combination of select-object and format-list, but I'm not sure exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can retrieve that from the `IdentityReference` property of the `Access` property of `get-acl`. Here's an example from my user folder:

```
PS C:\> $users = @((get-acl 'C:\users\myUser').Access | 
                 Select-Object -ExpandProperty IdentityReference)
PS C:\> $users

Value
-----
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
BUILTIN\Administrators
DOMAIN\myUser
```

The objects returned in the collection are of the type [NTAccount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.ntaccount.aspx).